# Xamarin Android Modal Popup not really modal?

Tags: android, xamarin

I've been working on a Xamarin project for a while and noticed that when I use:

await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);

It shows the page... and then just keeps going. It does not stop to wait for the 'modal' page to close.

I'm not really sure what the point of calling this 'Modal' is and I wanted to be sure I was not missing some obvious thing. It seems to be exactly like Navigation.PushAsync(). I googled and all I found was just standard implementation examples.

I am used to 'modal' meaning that all processing stops in the calling code until the form closes.

```
    try
    {
        _loaded = false;

        // TEST
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("About to push modal");
        ModalPage page = new ModalPage();
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Page is still showing. Not going to wait.");
        // TEST
```

I have a work around but it's kind of clunky and I was hoping there was a better way.

```
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("About to push modal");
    ModalPage page = new ModalPage();
    Guid pageId = page.Id;
    Guid currId = pageId;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    await Task.Delay(250);
    while (pageId == currId)
    {
        await Task.Delay(250);
        currId = Guid.Empty;
        int index = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1;
        if (index > 0)
            currId = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[index].Id;
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Page was closed. Safe to move on.");
```

Comment: "modal" means that the window is the only UI the user can interact with until the modal is dismissed.  It doesn't mean that it blocks any other app code from running

Comment: I'm used to being able to prompt the user for information in Windows and waiting for a reply. I don't see any point to this form of 'modal' behavior.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Comment: XCT has a Navigation.ShowPopupAsync() that can return a string value from the popup

Comment: As mentioned above `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);` does not return a result like XCT popup it simply waits for the page to be pushed onto the ModalStack.

Comment: Even Windows does not work the way you're describing. An app that's entirely driven by user interaction may not visibly do anything when displaying a modal dialog, but that's not because it can't.

Comment: In Windows the calling window is effectively 'frozen' and the call to Form.ShowDialog() is blocked until the form closed. Honestly I can not see any functional difference between PushAsync and PushAsyncModal.

Comment: It might seem like nitpicking terminology, but you're talking about the fact that `Form.ShowDialog()` is blocking. The function blocking and the modality of the resulting dialog are entirely separate concepts that do not necessarily go hand in hand.

Comment: The wikipedia article I linked above states that modal is defined by such blocking. I don't know what else 'modal' would mean. Just popping up another form while continuing the processing on the calling form is identical to what PushAsync does.

Comment: @Belmiris If that's what the wiki says, then it's just plain wrong. Modality is defined by blocking interaction with the parent UI, period. It has absolutely nothing to do with blocking in the sense of blocking vs. non-blocking functions. And in most UI frameworks, it's not implemented as a blocking function. The behavior you're trying to reproduce is weird.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I can see no other useful definition of 'modal'. The current functionality is worthless. There is no point to it. I even tried a test and the controls on the calling form still receive focus if you use a timer so it's not even useful for that limited scope. Xamarin has an actual, working, modal dialog that can be used, DisplayAlert(). You know, so the developer can ask the user a question before making a decision. I challenge you to come up with a useful example of how these 'modal' pages are in any way different than 'non-modal' pages other than they use different stacks.

Comment: Blocking interaction with the UI is useful. Blocking program flow is tricky to implement (as you've discovered) and the paradigm has either been abandoned or was never included in most UI frameworks. Properly conceptualized, event driven UI frameworks don't even *have* the linear program flow you're trying to block. You can still ask a question before making a decision. Just block the UI and display a dialog that does one thing or the other. If this is insufficient, it hints that the entire structure of the program is fighting the event driven paradigm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is (in my opinion) no, the PushModalAsync() does not create what a Windows Desktop developer would consider a Modal dialog page. I cannot see any real difference between it and PushAsync(). It was stated in the comments that the parent window won't accept user input but pages take up the whole screen so I can't test it and it functionally doesn't matter.

I made a more formal workaround and made it part of a PageService I use in my application. Maybe it can help someone else.

```
public class PageService : IPageService
{
    public async Task<Page> ShowPageModal(Type pageType, params object[] paramArray)
    {
        Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType, args: paramArray);
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
        int interval = 1000;
        Guid pid;
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(interval);
            interval = 250;
            pid = GetCurrentModalPageId();
        } while (pid == page.Id);

        return page;
    }

    public Guid GetCurrentModalPageId()
    {
        Guid id = Guid.Empty;
        int index = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count - 1;
        if (index >= 0)
            id = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack[index].Id;
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is an example call:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender == TestButton)
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Potato Salad", "Joe Bob" };
            LookupPages.ModalSelectPage page = (LookupPages.ModalSelectPage) await PageService.ShowPageModal(typeof(LookupPages.ModalSelectPage), new object[] { "Select a String", items });
            string item = page.SelectedItem;
            await DisplayAlert("Modal Select Result", item ?? "null", "Ok");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        App.HandleError(ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the Page I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StoreTrak.Pages.LookupPages.ModalSelectPage">
    <!-- Start Page Layout -->
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" FontAttributes="Bold,Italic" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        
        <StackLayout Margin="10,0,10,0" 
                     BackgroundColor="White" 
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <!-- 3: List of items -->
            <ListView x:Name="itemsList" 
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      Margin="5,0,5,0"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      ItemTapped="itemsList_ItemTapped">
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- 4: Back and Main buttons -->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    Padding="10" 
                    VerticalOptions="End">
            <Button x:Name="BackButton"
                    Style="{StaticResource back}" 
                    Clicked="BackButton_Clicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace StoreTrak.Pages.LookupPages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ModalSelectPage : ContentPage
    {
        List<string> _items = null;
        string _title = "Select Something";

        public ModalSelectPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ModalSelectPage(string title, List<string> items)
            : this()
        {
            _items = items;
            _title = title;
        }

        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnAppearing();

                TitleLabel.Text = _title ?? "Select Something";

                if (_items != null && _items.Count > 0)
                {
                    itemsList.ItemsSource = _items;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }

        private async void BackButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }

        private void itemsList_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SelectedItem = e.Item as string;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more useful approach would be to use a generic method and encapsulate all the information into the Page class. That way you can use the same method for any page with any data types that need to be selected.

In the PageService

```
public async Task ModalPopup<T>(T page) where T : Page
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
    int interval = 1000;
    Guid pid;
    do
    {
        await Task.Delay(interval);
        interval = 250;
        pid = GetCurrentModalPageId();
    } while (pid == page.Id);
}
```

Adjust the ModalSelectPage class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace StoreTrak.Pages.LookupPages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ModalSelectPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ModalSelectPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ModalSelectPage(string title, List<string> items)
            : this()
        {
            ItemList = items;
            TitleText = title;
        }

        public List<string> ItemList { get; set; }

        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

        public string TitleText { get; set; } = "Select Something";

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnAppearing();

                TitleLabel.Text = TitleText ?? "Select Something";

                if (ItemList != null && ItemList.Count > 0)
                {
                    itemsList.ItemsSource = ItemList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }

        private async void BackButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }

        private void itemsList_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SelectedItem = e.Item as string;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can pass any Page to it:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender == TestButton)
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Potato Salad", "Joe Bob" };
            LookupPages.ModalSelectPage page = new LookupPages.ModalSelectPage { TitleText = "Select a String", ItemList = items };
            await PageService.ModalPopup(page);
            string item = page.SelectedItem;
            await DisplayAlert("Modal Select Result", item ?? "null", "Ok");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        App.HandleError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to put 'Modal' in the name of the page to remind yourself to call PopModalAsync rather than PopAsync when closing the page. For some reason they are on different 'stacks' and you get a less than friendly error if you call the wrong one.